# generate result from result of other query mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is my table

[image]

From above

my query is

```
SELECT count_id, COUNT( questionID ) AS qid
FROM `sg_count`
GROUP BY count_id
```

it will get output [image]

i also want to to count (count_id) who has qid <5 using result of first query

Comment: You can try to filter the results in php itself after you get the first query. This would be more easy.

Comment: What would you like to be the exact output for the sample data you're providing?

Comment: i want to count(count_id) where qid >3 0r any condition after first query execution

Comment: @sush .. when it can be done with the query why to code extra?

Comment: @sgt You're right :)

Comment: @NikhilMusale You want _only_ the count, not the rest of the data?

Comment: Add servay Table Image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this -

```
"SELECT count(qid) FROM (
    SELECT count_id, COUNT( questionID ) AS qid FROM `sg_count` GROUP BY count_id
) as count_data where qid < 5" ;
```